# Make an image immune to page zoom on a web page in iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, zooming

I want to place an image in a web page so that when it is viewed on an ipad and zoomed in the image size stays the same. How can this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103842/safari-ipad-prevent-zoom-on-double-tap
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221446/iphone-detect-zoom-help

Answer (score 1):

You would simply add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
```

To prevent the user from zooming in.